# Rails set page title in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

How can I set the page title in some views and use a default title if it's not set?
I use HAML. What is right way of doing it?

Now I do like:

```
- content_for :title, "Title for specific page"
```

and in layout:

```
%title= h yield(:title)
```

But how to set this title, but if it doesn't exist, set some default value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `content_for?` method as described in the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for-3F)

```
content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "default title"
```